# Examples of puzzles

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, computer-science, puzzle

So, an example of PUZZLE which its time complexity is linear is the problem of searching for a specific value in an array: it is easy to prove you can't do it with less than n comparsions, and we have an algorithm which solves this problem in exactly linear time O(n).

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for SO; please do your own research, and review the material in the Help Center.

Comment: Do you have any guesses as to what might be correct examples? We can help you understand why those are correct or wrong if you demonstrate that you have put some thought into the problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quadratic: given a list of N integers and an arbitrary Boolean function `f` on pairs of integers, determine whether there exists a pair of integers `x, y` I the list such that `f(x, y) = true`.

Exponential: given a list of N integers and an arbitrary Boolean function `f` on sets of integers, determine whether there exists a set `S` of integers taken from the list such that `f(S) = true`.

In each case, we *can* solve the problem by considering all pairs/subsets. In each case, we *can't* do any better if the function is arbitrary and provided as input. The time complexity is of course affected by the encoding of the function, but that is fixed w.r.t. the size of the list.

You might object that we could build a general-purpose "function understander" to more intelligently look for pairs/subsets. However, this isn't possible for basically the same reason the halting problem's undecidable: for an arbitrary program, it's hard to tell what it's doing (or, for an arbitrary function, it's hard to tell what it computes).